# When submitting comment form Fatal error: Class 'Api' not found

Tags: htaccess, comment-form

My problem: I could submit a comment, but the data wouldn´t be saved into the database. But no error message was shown. After submisseion EE would just take the comment, throw it away and then would show the SE-page again.

Checked around, found [this tip here on EESE](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/616/comment-form-missing-xid-form-submits-but-data-doesnt-save/617#617), got rid of the NSM htaccess generator. Now I´m back to the normal index.php-Syntax.

Now I can submit Comments, but I get the following error message, when I submit a comment as a logged in user

```
Fatal error: Class 'Api' not found in {removed}/system/expressionengine/
libraries/api/Api_channel_fields.php on line 3
```

When I comment as a non-logged in user I just get a blank page.

But the comments are saved. I can see and edit them in the CP and the comments are attached to the respective entry. So, the process works, I "just" need to get riod of the error message and have EE return to the SE-page.

I tried to set the return value as

```
return="entry/index/url_title"
```

but this didn´t work.

I checked the Api_channel_fields.php. This is what I see in line 3

```
class Api_channel_fields extends Api {
```

I even uploaded a fresh Api_channel_fields.php from my installation package.
Nothing helped. Any thoughts, how I can fix that?
I would love to get the .htaccess back to work, but for now I´d be happy to just get rid of the fatal error

**Edit to answer Adrian Macneil questions**

What other plugins/extensions are you using? 
1. BW Channel Count
2. Channel Videos
3. Content Elements
4. Developer
5. HJ Social Bookmarks
6. Entry Type
7. httpHeader
8. ImageSizer
9. Low Nospam
10. Low Replace
11. Low Seg2cat
12. Minimee
13. NSM Morphine
14. PDF Press
15. PT Fieldpack
16. Recent Entries
17. Republic Variables
18. SuperGeekery Tag Stripper
19. Sitemap
20. Taggable
21. Template Variables
22. TruncHTML

Are you using the built in EE comment form? Yes, I copied the code from the EE help pages and adapted it. The comment module is on.
This is my template code

```
{exp:comment:form channel="artikel"}
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Ihr Kommentar</legend>
        <label for="name">Name (erforderlich)</label> 
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{name}"/>
        <label for="email">E-Mail (erforderlich, wird nicht ver&ouml;ffentlicht)</label>
        <input type="text" class="twelve" name="email" value="{email}" />
        <label for="url">Web-Site</label>
        <input type="text" class="twelve" name="url" value="{url}" />
        <label for="comment">Ihr Kommentar</label>
        <textarea name="comment">{comment}</textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Kommentar absenden" />
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </fieldset>
{/exp:comment:form}
```

This is the code as it is rendered on the SE-page

```
<form id="comment_form" method="post" action="http://www.bandikutmedia.de/eintrag/journalisten-auf-die-rote-liste"  >
    <div class='hiddenFields'>
        <input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="RET" value="http://www.bandikutmedia.de/eintrag/journalisten-auf-die-rote-liste" />
        <input type="hidden" name="URI" value="eintrag/journalisten-auf-die-rote-liste" />
        <input type="hidden" name="PRV" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="31203ae5e27a3ba65d1cbaec73d7ae6ea2ba9fc8" />
        <input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="33" />
        <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
    </div>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Ihr Kommentar</legend>
        <label for="name">Name (erforderlich)</label> 
        <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
        <label for="email">E-Mail (erforderlich, wird nicht ver&ouml;ffentlicht)</label>
        <input type="text" class="twelve" name="email" value="" />
        <label for="url">Web-Site</label>
        <input type="text" class="twelve" name="url" value="http://" />
        <label for="comment">Ihr Kommentar</label>
        <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Kommentar absenden" />
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What other plugins/extensions are you using? Are you using the built in EE comment form? This is almost certainly a bug, we just need to help you figure out which add-on is causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok- so the issue for me turned out to be "Content Elements" plugin from Krea. After disabling this, the errors went away!

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I recommend you report this to Krea as well (if you haven't already done so) so they can get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Please download new Content Elements 1.1.1 release: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/content-elements

We have fixed problem with comments.

Thank you,
team Krea

Comment: This fixed it for me too. Problem solved