# Issue with comments - "You are not authorized to perform this action"

Tags: comments

What could cause commenting to suddenly not work for a particular channel if no changes to the configuration has been made? The person trying to comment gets the message "You are not authorized to perform this action". The EE version is 2.9.0 and there's been no upgrade between now and the last successful comment.

Comment: I am still having the same issue and would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing locally (e.g. using the “localhost” domain) you may get this security error on comments submission. To test commenting during local development, try to set "Require IP Address and User Agent for Posting" to "No" in Admin -> Security and Privacy -> Security and Sessions.

Comment: This is on a live site that has been live for a long time and where comments from guests have worked fine before.

Answer (score 0):

The "You are not authorized to perform this action" error can occur under these two situations (in addition to other situations too):

1. When EE determines that a posted comment is a duplicate. So if you keep posting a comment with "test" as the copy, EE will trigger the error.
2. When a person submits a comment and then uses their back button to post a second comment.

Comment: It definitely wasn't 2. and I tested again to rule out 1. and it doesn't seem to be that either as it doesn't go through no matter what I write.

Comment: Check your config.php file... Do you see a setting for "secure_forms"? What is it set to?

Comment: I don't seem to have a setting for secure_forms defined, no.

Comment: Try adding it and set to "n" and retest.

Comment: Do I need to do anything after editing config.php to make sure it takes effect? If not, it didn't solve it, still getting the same error.

Comment: You don't need to do anything except test. So adding that to the config eliminates one issue of EE's security settings potentially being the problem. You can remove it. NEXT, I would check all the settings for your GUEST member group OR the member group that is posting comments. Check to make sure their permissions to post comments didn't change.

Comment: ALSO... Check the rendered code for your comment form. Do you see a hidden input field with name="XID"?

Comment: Its the Guest group and they are set to be able to comment and to get moderated. I even tried flipping the setting off and then on again to see if that helped, but no go. There's no name="XID" anywhere on the page in the rendered code.

Comment: Do me a favor, remove everything from your .htaccess file and just use the official code for removing index.php and retest submitting comments: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html#create-an-htaccess-file.... This is detailed on this page (http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/628/28)

Comment: Also... please add this exact code to your config.php file again and retest::::  $config['secure_forms'] = "n";

Comment: I don't think the official code will work at all for me since I am working in actual (not virtual) subfolders as well. I'll give it a quick try without any rewriting at all though, to see if that works. As for the config, that is the exact code I used.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured out how to use the official code at least in this scenario, so I stripped out my code and replaced it with the official, setting it up for the particular subdirectory that we're testing in. I also made the change to config.php. The error still remains. I have now switched back the rewrite again, so the rest of the site works.